# mod_python/MySQL error on INSERT with a lot of data: "OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')"

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, mysql-error-2006

When doing an INSERT with a lot of data, ie:

```
INSERT INTO table (mediumtext_field) VALUES ('...lots of text here: about 2MB worth...')
```

MySQL returns

> "OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')"

This is happening within a minute of starting the script, so it is not a timeout issue. Also, `mediumtext_field` should be able to hold ~16MB of data, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Any ideas what is causing the error or how to work around it?

Some relevant libraries being used: `mod_python 3.3.1`, `MySQL 5.0.51` (on Windows XP SP3, via xampp, details below)

**ApacheFriends XAMPP (basic package) version 1.6.5**

- Apache 2.2.6
- MySQL 5.0.51
- phpMyAdmin 2.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the max_packet setting in your my.cnf file. this determines the largest amount of data you can send to your mysql server in a single statement. exceeding this values results in that error.